# how to set update priority for Flexible or Immediate update request on play console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

i am implementing in app updates. can anyone guide me how to set update priority for Flexible or Immediate update request on play console

Comment: I have the same issue and I know it is only possible using the [Google Developer APIs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) and you can look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) for getting started.

Comment: @msc87 I dont understand why API call is required, why there is no option to set this priority from the normal Developers console? :/